How to integrate comments feature in my 360 viewer sdk
I am using autodesk viewer 360 sdk in my webapp.
I want to add comments feature same as the online free version of autodesk viewer. How can I do that? Is there any other APIs I need to use? Or I can do that with any extensions available in autodesk?

Unfortunately, the API does not provide a way to do it directly - no extension related to that is public. You'd have to implement it yourself.
